# java generics - method return type

Tags: java, generics

say i have a class Animal, and then classes Dog and Cat that extend it. Can i have a method then that returns dog or cat, depending on some value? so, something like this, except working :)

```
public <T extends Animal> getAnimal(){
  if (a)
    return new Dog();
  else
    return new Cat();
}
```

Comment: In c# you need to cast.

Comment: You don't need generics for this.  Just:
public Animal getAnimal(bool a) 
should do the trick, provided both Dog and Cat do extend Animal.

Comment: He is probably experimenting.

Comment: @ChaosPandion - we all did. Usually in college, though - and not with animals.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to use Generics in that situation. Simply making the return type `Animal` will allow returning any of `Animal`'s subclasses. However, you need to add that crazy Generics stuff when dealing with Collections as return types. IE.

```
private List<T extends Animal> method1() {
    return new ArrayList<Dog>();
}

private List<? super Dog> method() {
    return new ArrayList<Animal>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use generics in this situation.  You could create a factory type method which returns an Animal object:

```
Animal GetAnimal( AnimalType type )
{
    switch ( type )
    {
        case AnimalType.Dog:
            return new Dog( );
            break;
        case AnimalType.Cat:
            return new Cat( );
            break;
    }       
}
```

Sorry if the syntax is off a bit, I don't use Java.

Comment: That's legal Java as well as C#. The uppercase method name is more idiomatic for C# but I think it would compile.

Comment: Just guessing at the "question behind the question": There's no way that the caller of your function can auto-magically know whether it has received a Dog or a Cat. The search term for that is "type erasure". In short, even with generics, there's now way to get Dog d = getAnimal(AnimalType.Dog) to compile.

Answer (score -1):

```
public <T extends Animal> T getAnimal(){
  if (a)
    return (T) new Dog();
  else
    return (T) new Cat();
}
```

Comment: -1 This isn't type safe, for example you could write `Fish f = this.<Fish>getAnimal();` and it would compile.